Why is Tar speed not same?
I heard somewhere on the Internet that cpio is faster than tar.
So I tried to check it with my shell script.
#1/bin/bash

rm ct.tar ct.cpio
sync && sudo sh -c "/usr/bin/echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"  #nocache

start="$(date -u +%s.%N)"
tar cf cpiotar.tar
end="$(date -u +%s.%N)"
elipsed="$(bc <<<"$end-$start")"
echo "tar $elapsed"

sync && sudo sh -c "/usr/bin/echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"  #nocache

start="$(date -u +%s.%N)"
find $1 -depth | cpio -o > ct.cpio
end="$(date -u +%s.%N)"
elapsed="$(bc <<<"$end-$start")"
echo "cpio $elapsed"

This shell script archive 'parameter' directory and check time elapsed.
I ran script with a directory whose size is nearly 1GB.
The result is below.
tar 74.157502069
cpio 10.269119009

and if I run script again, the result is below.
tar 3.335409300
cpio 7.097516017

The result is really weird.
tar suddenly became dramatically fast, since cpio show no difference.
Why did this happen?

What kind of system are you running that on? Is that in a VM (whose host system will also have its own cache)? On what type of filesystem? Is that a local ext4 or btrfs filesystem, or a remove filesystem (NFS, SMB?)? If local, on what kind of storage? HDD, SSD, RAIDed...?

"I read on the internet that cpio is faster than tar." such information is often hearsay, and even where it isn't, does change drastically with software versions and different storage media. I would generally not heed much attention to such sweeping statements! I like how you chose to vertify rather than to believe :)

You're probably dealing with write caching:
If you want to measure filesystem performance please always do it this way:
$ echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
$ time ( your_commands; sync )

In your examples you seemingly did not invoke sync after writing/creating files.
Write buffering means when you create a file on the filesystem it doesn't automatically get written to your underlying storage right away. There might be a considerable delay.
More on this:

https://www.baeldung.com/linux/file-system-caching
https://medium.com/marionete/linux-disk-cache-was-always-there-741bef097e7f


hm, good point, but when I try, that doesn't change the benchmark results significantly. How much does it change them for you?

Made a 2GB tar/cpio in my very old HDD, for cpio real 0m34.472s user 0m1.504s sys 0m4.102s, for tar real 0m36.180s user 0m0.056s sys 0m1.649s - nothing to write home about. 1.5 seconds difference within a margin of error. Repeated the same on tmpfs and thousands of small files, 720MB directory: tar real 0m0.163s user 0m0.005s sys 0m0.158s cpio `1445588 blocks
real 0m0.810s
user 0m0.270s
sys 0m0.542sobviously cpio is 5 times slower because of extrafind` and pipe.
